# Operator Semigroup: Resolvent estimates and stabilization, a detail in the paper of Nicoulas Burq and Patrick Gerard

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, semigroups-of-operators

In **Appendix A** of the paper **Stabilization of wave equations on the torus with rough dampings** https://msp.org/paa/2020/2-3/p04.xhtml or https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00983 by Nicoulas Burq and Patrick Gerard.

The author states a equivalent relation:

Supposed that $e^{tA}$ is a strongly continuous semigroups on a Hilbert space $H$ with infinitesimal generator $A$ defined on $D(A)$. The following two properties are equivalent:

(1) There exist $C,\delta>0$ such that the resolvent of $A$, $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ exists for the real part of $\lambda$, $\rm{Re}\ \lambda\geq-\delta$ and satisfies $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C}^{\delta}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\rm{Re}\ z\geq-\delta\}$, we have $\|(A-\lambda)^{-1}\|_{\mathscr{L}(
H)}\leq C$.

(2)There exist $M,\delta>0$ such that for any $t>0$, $\|e^{tA}\|_{\mathscr{L}(
H)}\leq Me^{-\delta t}$.

Confusion of the proof: When proving $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, the authors say "Since $v(t)$ is supported in $t\in[-1,0]$, the right side hand in $(i\tau+\omega-A)\hat{u}(\tau)=\hat{v}(\tau)$" is holomorphic and bounded in any domain $\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}=\{\tau\in\mathbb{C}:\rm{Im}\ \tau\geq\alpha,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$($\color{red}{why?}$)."

In the next line, the authors say:

"From the assumption on the resolvent, we deduce that $\hat{u}$ admits a holomorphic extension to $\{\tau: \rm{Im} \tau\leq\delta+\omega\}$ which satisfies $\|\hat{u}(\tau)\|_{H}\leq C\|\hat{v}(\tau)\|_{H}$($\color{red}{why?}$)"

Why should we consider the holomorphic extension of $\hat{u}$(**the time fourier transform of $u$**)
thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Just for the record: As the authors of the paper point out in the first sentence of Appendix A.1, this is actually a very classical and well-known theorem in the theory of $C_0$-semigroups. It's commonly referred to as the *Gearhart-Prüß theorem* and it's proof is explained in detail in standard books on the topic (so I'm not quite sure why the authors recall the proof in the appendix of the paper). See for instance Theorem V.1.11 on page 302 of the [semigroup book](https://zbmath.org/0952.47036) by Engel and Nagel.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, thank you professor. I guess that it is for readers' convenient. And just now, I read the semigroup book of Engel and Nagel, and find that the proof in the paper is more easier(It means that it doesn't need too much preliminaries) than the book.

Comment: @JochenGlueck thank you for your explanation! I also want to know where can I find the standard material of the asymptotic behavior of semigroup and eventually, you tell me this fact, thank you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first "why": that $\hat{v}(\tau)$ is holomorphic is a version of [Paley-Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem). On the domain $\mathbb{C}_\alpha$ you have $\exp(i\tau t)$ is uniformly bounded (for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$) by $\exp(-\alpha)$), so as long as $v(t)$ is integrable in $t$ the boundedness claim follows.

For the second "why":  Setting $\lambda = \omega + i\tau$ then
$$ \mathrm{Re}(\lambda) \geq -\delta \iff \mathrm{Re}(i\tau) \geq -\delta-\omega \iff - \mathrm{Im}(\tau) \geq - (\delta + \omega) $$
So the resolvent assumption shows that $(i\tau + \omega - A)$ is invertible with bounded inverse. That the resolvent is holomorphic in $\lambda$ is standard. So you can invert $(i\tau + \omega - A)\hat{u}(\tau) = \hat{v}(\tau)$ to get the claim.

As for the final question, the following is a bit of an imprecise heuristic: using the Fourier inversion formula, you have (up to some constants)
$$ u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{u}(\tau) \exp(it\tau) d\tau$$
If $\hat{u}$ has a holomorphic extension to a strip around the real line, this integral should be equal to (up to terms at infinity)
$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \hat{u}(\tau+i\epsilon) \exp(it(\tau + i\epsilon)) d\tau$$
But now $\exp(it(\tau + i\epsilon))$ has a uniform decay like $\exp(-\epsilon t)$ so you expect the same to hold for $u(t)$. So at least at a formal level you see that having a holomorphic extension to a strip of $\hat{u}$ is connected to the function $u$ having exponential decay.

Comment: Thank you for your patient explaination,  PROFESSOR! I learn a lot from your answer. And I am very happy for receiving such a insightful  answer from you.  When studying the work of Burq and Gerard about the energy decay rate of damping wave equation,  I often meet with problems concerning details like the above and I struggle a longtime on the detail(like microlocal analysis, kinds of geometric control conditions), can you give me some suggestions on how to read their paper efficiently(maybe I have a poor foundation)?  Thanks again Best wishes!

Comment: @monotoneoperator I am not really the person to ask about damped waves; I only happen to know a little bit about the subject through osmosis from conversations [emphasis: not reading papers!] I've had with a postdoc (Perry Kleinhenz) whom I am half-supervising. It is a lot easier when things are explained to you by a patient person.

Comment: thank you! I can not agree with you more. My phd adviser never care my study and research and so I have to study by myself. When I encounter with some difficulties, I have to struggle with this problems and always stay a long time on the detail. I feel painful. Thank you for your answer again, and you let me feel happy! In addition, I also read a little Perry Kleinhenz's paper last month.